# Word and Excel addins give errors when repeatedly clicking on the button in the Ribbon

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I sideloaded the Word addin from:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/tree/master/Simple

When I click multiple times on the button in the Ribbon, typically thirty times, an error dialog appears saying that the add in could not be started.

[Word error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95vxG.png)

The problem occurs even if the executed function doesn't do anything. For example:

```
function executeFunctionFromRibbon(event) {
   event.completed();
}
```

The same problem occurs in Excel.

Is there a known bug in Office executing functions from the Ribbon that causes this error?

Is anybody able to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Which or the 3 buttons in that sample are you clicking? Are you clicking rapidly or spread out over time?

Comment: I click the first button 'Execute Function' and it doesn't matter if I click rapidly or spread out over time.